# Can I automatically create a header file based on an existing .cpp file in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

Can I automatically create a header file in Visual Studio based on an existing `.cpp` file, where the header file automatically contains the declarations of all the methods in the `.cpp` file?

Comment: It's generally impossible to guess what should go into .h and what should stay in .cpp

Comment: C++20's **modules** may help.